# Subquery in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

My problem is that out of two tables I need a result set presenting the number of ordered items per PLU and the number of items still on stock.

I cannot do it in ONE stored procedure.

My query presenting the orders.

```
SELECT 
    tblOrderDetails.PLU, tblArtikel.Description, 
    SUM(tblOrderDetails.Pieces) AS Pieces
FROM 
    tblOrderDetails 
INNER JOIN
    tblArtikel ON tblOrderDetails.PLU = tblArtikel.PLU 
GROUP BY 
    tblOrderDetails.PLU, tblArtikel.Description
```

returns as output:

```
30002 BA4875 3  
30012 UK8798 15
```

My stock is queried with

```
(SELECT SUM(tblStock.Pieces) AS Ls, tblStock.PLU
from tblStock
GROUP BY tblStock.PLU)
```

The result should look like:

```
30002 BA4875 3  0   
30012 UK8798 15  8
```

meaning that for artikelno 30002 there are 3 ordered and 0 on stock

So, how can I combine both queries (resultsets) in one SP?

I always get error

> Msg 116
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I know what the error is, but without the PLU in the stock-query I do not know how to combine both resultsets.

Thanks yr. help
Michael

Comment: does these queries have any fields in common?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below

```
SELECT 
tblOrderDetails.PLU, tblArtikel.Description, 
SUM(tblOrderDetails.Pieces) AS Pieces
FROM  tblOrderDetails 
INNER JOIN  tblArtikel ON tblOrderDetails.PLU = tblArtikel.PLU 
where exists 
(
    select SUM(tblStock.Pieces) AS Ls, tblStock.PLU from tblStock 
    where  tblArtikel.PLU = tblStock.PLU       
    GROUP BY tblStock.PLU
    having SUM(tblStock.Pieces) > 0
)
GROUP BY tblOrderDetails.PLU, tblArtikel.Description
```

Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks your efforts, but it misses still the second sum, the items on stock. Your code just sums up the ordered items.   Meanwhile I found a solution for it and it works:   I made a table-valued-function calculating the items on stock and joined it with "outer apply" with the ordered table.